# Display a basic 1.6 million points Heatmap

Tags: heatmap, lightningchart

I'm new to lightning chart (and js overall) and I want to display basic heatmap values ( coordinates and a value {"x":-32,"y":-31,"heat":73.77} ), but 1.6 million of them who are on a json file.

What's the best way to do it ? At least is it the best way to do it ?

I couldn't find basic ressources to test with, only complicated models.

Thanks a lot by advance !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

**LightningChart JS heatmaps**

Please refer to the official LightningChart JS heatmap examples gallery for learning and testing heatmap features.

The ["JavaScript Heatmap Grid Chart"](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0800-heatmapGrid.html) example is the most basic one and its description goes through the available options and input data format.

To see all available heatmap examples, select the ["heatmap" tag](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/search.html?t=heatmap).

**Your dataset**

Your dataset seems to be a scatter type, meaning that the data points are not ordered but have the X and Y coordinate information in them. LightningChart JS heatmaps can only read symmetrically ordered value matrixes, as described further in the example.

In order to supply your data set into a heatmap, you need to implement an algorithm that places only your "heat" values into a symmetric ordered matrix.

Comment: Or you could also use PointSeries, input data set as is and use PalettedFill, similarly as in this example https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0019-flowCytometryChart.html?theme=lightNew&page-theme=light